# Confused about the Mysql lock

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level

I have a question about MySQL InnoDB. For example: I have thread A to start a transaction:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update user set name = "Jim" where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

And then, I just leave the thread A as it is.  I started another thread B to do this:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update user set name = "Tom" where id = 1;
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

It makes sense, because thread A put a 'X' lock on that row.

And then I used thread B to do this:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from user where id = 1;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | wlq3 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here I'm confused. Like I just said thread A put a 'X' lock on that row. why thread B can read this row. In my opinion, reading data need a share lock, but exclusive lock is already on that data. Is there anyone can help me ,thanks!

By the way, the isolation level of thread A is repeatable read, and thread B is read committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `wlq3` is the committed value in the database so transaction B reads this value. The update with `Jim` has not committed yet.A lock will not block a read it will just block a update this is due to the MVCC locking model which is implemented in InnoDB.

See this link for more information: [InnoDB's row locking the same as MVCC Non-Blocking Reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321647/innodbs-row-locking-the-same-as-mvcc-non-blocking-reads)